# Get uptime of a window process in java

Tags: java

I have written a code which will give me all the processes which are currently running on Windows and their instances count. I have also written a code which will kill a process by name specified. But I want to kill the process which has the most uptime, for example if I have 5 instances running for *notepad* then I want to kill only one instance which has the highest uptime. Below is the code which I have written. Thanks in advance.

```java
public static void method3() {
    List<String>processes=new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String,Integer>mp=new LinkedHashMap<>();
    try {
        String line;
        Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist.exe /fo csv /nh");
        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if (!line.trim().equals("")) {
                line = line.substring(0,line.indexOf(","));
                line=line.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
                processes.add(line);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();

        //Putting process name and it's instances count into a map.
        for(int i=0;i<processes.size();i++) {
            int count=Collections.frequency(processes,processes.get(i));
            mp.put(processes.get(i),count);
        }

        //getting specific value count and killing a processes if it is active based on name.
        Set<String>key=mp.keySet();
        for(String k:key) {
            if(k.equalsIgnoreCase("notepad.exe")) {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM "+k);
            }
        }

        for(Entry<String, Integer> ent:mp.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(ent.getKey()+"="+ent.getValue());
        }
        in.close();
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using at least JDK 9, you can use the [Process API](https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-process-api) that was added since that version. Method [allProcesses](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html) returns a [stream](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2.html) of all the current processes.

You filter for the processes containing the relevant name (in your question you use *notepad.exe*) and sort them by [totalCpuDuration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessHandle.Info.html#totalCpuDuration--) and collect them to a list where the last element in the list is the process with *the highest uptime*, i.e. the longest [duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

As far as I am aware, the *Process API* does not have a method for killing a process, hence I used class [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) for that.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class TaskList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "notepad.exe";
        List<ProcessHandle> list = ProcessHandle.allProcesses() // returns 'Stream<ProcessHandle>'
                                                .filter(h -> h.info()
                                                              .command() // returns 'Optional<String>'
                                                              .orElse("") // returns path to executable file or empty string
                                                              .contains(s))
                                                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(h -> h.info()
                                                                                   .totalCpuDuration() // returns 'Optional<Duration>'
                                                                                   .orElse(Duration.ZERO))) // returns actual duration or a "zero" duration
                                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        int count = list.size();
        if (count > 0) {
            long pid = list.get(count - 1)
                           .pid();
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("taskkill", "/PID", Long.toString(pid));
            pb.inheritIO();
            try {
                Process p = pb.start();
                int status = p.waitFor();
                System.out.println("status = " + status);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException | IOException x) {
                x.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.printf("No '%s' process found.%n", s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea I think this can work.Is there a way to get the start time of the process through this code>

Comment: @Madsinceborn refer to method [startInstant](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessHandle.Info.html#startInstant()) of interface `ProcessHandle.Info`. You can convert the `Instant` to a timestamp. Refer to method [ofInstant](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#ofInstant(java.time.Instant,java.time.ZoneId)) in class `ZonedDateTime`.